# Resizing Divs using Javascript with a Parent and Child element

Tags: javascript

I have a view that sits on my Salesforce platform that is controlled by JavaScript and HTML. I have a requirement that because users have different responsibilities and needs they would like the ability to adjust their div sizes and views so it will be customized to the user.  The following is my div structure, any ideas how I can allow them to re-size this?  A future requirement will be that I save the layout/sizes of the divs so that's why I believe Javascript is a necessity..

**Edit to question:** It should be re-sized to how ever the user wants it so by Dragging (Just for height).

```
<div id="resizeMe" class="hp-onecolumn hp-sectionpad">
    <div class="hp-borders hp-boxcontainer" id="dvTripTask">
        <span class="hp-bluebox1"><h3 class="hp-header_label hp-headerpad">Trip Planning To Do List</h3><a HREF="#" onClick="openNewTab('/00Oa0000008W7DB?isdtp=vw');return false" id="btnReports">View Report</a>
            <span class="hp-range-container">
                <span class="ui-widget" targetId="TripTasks"><select id="drpTripTasksRanges" style="visibility:hidden;" class="drpRanges" targetId="TripTasks"></select></span>
                <span  class="hp-datepicker"><span id="lblTripTasksFrom">From: </span><input id="dpTripTasksFromDate" class="hp-datepicker_control hp-datefrom" targetId="TripTasks"/> To: <input id="dpTripTasksToDate" class="hp-datepicker_control hp-dateto" targetId="TripTasks"/></span>
            </span>
        </span>
        <div id="dvTripTaskInner" class="hp-innerbox">
            <div class="hp-innerboxpad">
                <table id="tblTripTasksList"></table>
                <div id="pgTripTask"> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="resizer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: How should it be resized?

Comment: By user dragging(height)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very fast mockup but this is the general idea. It shouldn't be hard to work the idea into your specific HTML. Let me know if you have any questions!

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mok38fur/5/

HTML:

```
<div id="resizeMe"></div>
<div id="resizer"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#resizeMe {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
}
#resizer {
    height: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
    cursor: row-resize;
}
```

JS:

```
var yAxisDrag;
var resizer;
var resizeMe;
var resizeMeHeight;

function makeResizable() {
    resizer = document.getElementById('resizer');
    resizeMe = document.getElementById('resizeMe');
    resizer.addEventListener('mousedown', initializeDrag);
};

function initializeDrag(event) {
    yAxisDrag = event.clientY;
    resizeMeHeight = resizeMe.offsetHeight;
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', onResizerDrag);
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', onStopResizerDrag);
};

function onResizerDrag(event) {
    var newResizeMeHeight = resizeMeHeight + event.clientY - yAxisDrag;
    if (newResizeMeHeight <= 30) {
        return;
    }
    resizeMe.style.height = newResizeMeHeight + 'px';
};

function onStopResizerDrag(event) {
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onResizerDrag);
    document.removeEventListener('mouseup', onStopResizerDrag);
};

makeResizable();
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I'll give this a try

Comment: Getting an error "Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null" At `resizer.addEventListener('mousedown', initializeDrag);`

Comment: @EricSSH Do you have an element with ID resizer?

Comment: I copied exactly what you had

Comment: @EricSSH I would need to see what you have because that error does not happen in the jsfiddle.

Comment: @EricSSH so you resolved the error you were getting?

Comment: I did, I made a mistake in the css

Comment: @EricSSH not sure how a CSS mistake could cause a null get element by id but glad you got past it. Let me know if you have other questions.

Comment: Yea no luck still getting that error i copied and pasted everything you had

Comment: @EricSSH I'm not sure you can just copy and paste it in. It needs to be changed to fit your html. I would need to see what you did. The only way you can get null from that line is if you don't have an element with that id

Comment: I know that, I'm just trying to stop from getting the error, are these not the elements? `<div id="resizeMe"></div>
<div id="resizer"></div>`

Comment: @EricSSH they are. Again I would need to see what you have because the fiddle I gave works. Why not try and reproduce your issue in a fiddle and I can help. I'm trying to help you there is only so much I can do without seeing what you have.

Comment: So resizer is null, I put a null check in and it runs but now it just won't move

Comment: @EricSSH resizer is what makes it all work. Eric. I can't help you unless I see your code. Reproduce the issue in a fiddle and I'll help but until I can see your code I can't do anything. I understand the error but I must see the code to tell you what is going wrong. Make a fiddle and I will show you what is wrong.

Comment: I cannot recreate the issue in fiddle, it works in fiddle i don't know why there is an issue on my side

Comment: @EricSSH can you show me your code in a pastebin or something. I'm really trying to help here man. But I'm reaching the limit of what can I offer or suggest.

Comment: @EricSSH no. I haven't been checking. But I thought you said you couldn't  reproduce it in fiddle?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96086/discussion-between-ericssh-and-atheistp3ace).

Comment: @EricSSH I just walked in from work. I can try and join in a bit when I get kids in bed. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use third party javascript libraries like jQuery and jQuery UI, I should recommend you to use [jQuery UI's Resizable plugin](http://jqueryui.com/resizable/).

Comment: Is it possible with this plugin to only allow it to adjust the height and not the width?

Comment: @EricSSH yes, you can lock the width using the `maxWidth` and `minWidth` options